# Reading CSV file and storing values into an array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, csv

I am trying to read a `*.csv`-file.

The `*.csv`-file consist of two columns separated by semicolon ("**;**").

I am able to read the `*.csv`-file using StreamReader and able to separate each line by using the `Split()` function. I want to store each column into a separate array and then display it.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: @Marc: unfortunately in non-english cultures (e.g. Italian) when you save an excel to CSV it uses `";"` as separator... this has made CSV a non-standard imo :(

Comment: I always read CSV as character-separated-values since people call files CSV even if they don't use a comma as separator. And there are so many dialects with different quoting or escaping rules in practice that you can't really talk of a standard even if in theory there is a RFC.

Comment: CSV file extension name should now get change to DSV - *Delimiter Separated Values* File

Comment: For all of the answers that simply split the string on the delimiter character, this is not the best way to go.  There are more rules to the CSV format that this will not cover.  It is best to use a 3rd party parser.  More info-  https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2018/08/04/csv-parsing-in-net-core/

Answer (score 585):

You can do it like this:

```
using System.IO;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using(var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\test.csv"))
    {
        List<string> listA = new List<string>();
        List<string> listB = new List<string>();
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var values = line.Split(';');

            listA.Add(values[0]);
            listB.Add(values[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: .EndOfStream is not available in .NET 1.1. Is while (reader.WriteLine) the way to go?

Comment: @ClayShannon The implementation of `EndOfStream` more or less checks to see if the current position of the reader is less than the length of the total number of bytes in the file. This works for me within my while constructor `rdr.BaseStream.Position < rdr.BaseStream.Length`. Remember a `StreamReader` is just a convenient wrapper around a `Stream` so with that being said you can implement your own custom methods if your version of .NET doesn't have them.

Comment: Does not handle field values with commas, etc.

Comment: Should use a `using` clause here, or at the very least manually `Close()` the `reader` as it's an `IDisposible` resource.

Comment: This also will not properly parse a CSV written like `column1;"Special ; char in string";column3` - https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180

Comment: It's risky to handle all edge cases in csv parsing by writing your own. It'd be better to use a package made for this. I liked the one from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16193999/375688) below.

Comment: I added a Console.WriteLine to loop through the list after the CSV is read into it. How would you go about telling the app that the CSV has headers? Just start at index 1 rather than 0?

Comment: I got a system.IndexOutOfRangeException on column2.Add(splits[1]);

Answer (score 280):

My favourite CSV parser is one built into .NET library. This is a hidden treasure inside Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace.
Below is a sample code:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;

var path = @"C:\Person.csv"; // Habeeb, "Dubai Media City, Dubai"
using (TextFieldParser csvParser = new TextFieldParser(path))
{
 csvParser.CommentTokens = new string[] { "#" };
 csvParser.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
 csvParser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

 // Skip the row with the column names
 csvParser.ReadLine();

 while (!csvParser.EndOfData)
 {
  // Read current line fields, pointer moves to the next line.
  string[] fields = csvParser.ReadFields();
  string Name = fields[0];
  string Address = fields[1];
 }
}
```

Remember to add reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic`

More details about the parser is given here: http://codeskaters.blogspot.ae/2015/11/c-easiest-csv-parser-built-in-net.html

Comment: I like this option the best. I don't have to worry about escape characters since the class is a CSV parser and not something being built manually.

Comment: In case anyone runs into this and is wondering, you'll need to include the reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic` framework assembly as it is not typically referenced by default.

Comment: I wish I had remembered this from my VB6 days, would have saved me a lot of time over the years.  While some will rant about VB, I have no issue adding the dll & namespace to my code if it has value.  This has A LOT of value.

Comment: Why only in VB dll?

Comment: This solution is way better than the other ones because it allows fields to have explicit values for comma's and new lines

Comment: It worked for me adjusting those lines  
csvParser.SetDelimiters(new string[] { ";", "\";\"" });
    csvParser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = false;

Answer (score 93):

LINQ way:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("test.txt").Select(a => a.Split(';'));
var csv = from line in lines
          select (from piece in line
                  select piece);
```

^^Wrong - **Edit by Nick**

It appears the original answerer was attempting to populate `csv` with a 2 dimensional array - an array containing arrays. Each item in the first array contains an array representing that line number with each item in the nested array containing the data for that specific column.

```
var csv = from line in lines
          select (line.Split(',')).ToArray();
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I'm not sure what the point of your csv variable is - aren't you just re-creating the same data structure that is alread in lines?

Comment: @Ben: I think you need to learn about either Link Wray or the LINQ way. Unfortunately for me, this won't work in .NET 1.1

Comment: @ClayShannon I'm farily fluent in LINQ, which is why I can't understand the point the statement, which (unless I'm missing something) results in exactly the same data structure as you started with.

Comment: @BenHughes You are right the LINQ is just duplicating the original data structure, and it's funny that it has so many upvotes - probably due to the fact that it looks concise, but a closer look reveals that this answer is not complete.

Comment: I also want to point out that csv's can be quoted... So using string.Split isn't a viable option.

Comment: I am getting: 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Split' and no extension method 'Split' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You are getting System.Array doesnt contain a definition because lines is an IEnumerable(string []) so line is basically a string array that has one element. Just change that to var csv = from line in lines select (line[0].Split(',')).ToArray();

Answer (score 58):

Just came across this library: https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper

Very intuitive and easy to use. Has a nuget package too which made is quick to implement: https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper. Also appears to be actively maintained which I like.

Configuring it to use a semi-colon is easy: https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/wiki/Custom-Configurations

Comment: How does the performance compare to `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser` (cf. @Habeeb's answer)?

Comment: That wiki link has been taken down.  The Api reference at https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/ still says coming soon, and despite the claim that it falls back to match Excel's parsing behavior, I cannot get it to open a csv file that Excel has no difficulty parsing.  It wasn't able to handle values separated by a comma followed by a space character.

Comment: This does not answer the question--it should be deleted or converted to a comment.

Answer (score 41):

You can't create an array immediately because you need to know the number of rows from the beginning (and this would require to read the csv file twice)

You can store values in two `List<T>` and then use them or convert into an array using `List<T>.ToArray()`

Very simple example:

```
var column1 = new List<string>();
var column2 = new List<string>();
using (var rd = new StreamReader("filename.csv"))
{
    while (!rd.EndOfStream)
    {
        var splits = rd.ReadLine().Split(';');
        column1.Add(splits[0]);
        column2.Add(splits[1]);
    }
}
// print column1
Console.WriteLine("Column 1:");
foreach (var element in column1)
    Console.WriteLine(element);

// print column2
Console.WriteLine("Column 2:");
foreach (var element in column2)
    Console.WriteLine(element);
```

N.B.

Please note that this is just a **very simple example**. Using `string.Split` does not account for cases where some records contain the separator `;` inside it.
For a safer approach, consider using some csv specific libraries like CsvHelper on nuget.

Comment: Does not account for `;` being a part of the value, example `"value with ; inside it"`. CSV surround values containing special characters with with double quotes to say it is a literal string.

Comment: @ChickenFeet: sure, that's the reason of the caption : *"Very simple example"*. Anyway I can add a note about that ;)

Comment: Regex.Split(sr.ReadLine(), ",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");  //Found this on SO...quicker than a library.

Answer (score 36):

I usually use this [parser from codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx), since there's a bunch of character escapes and similar that it handles for me.

Comment: This parser is available in the Nuget gallery as LumenWorks.Framework.IO, in case you don't want to register for CodeProject to download it.

Comment: This does not answer the question--it should be deleted or converted to a comment.

Answer (score 34):

Here is my variation of the top voted answer:

```
var contents = File.ReadAllText(filename).Split('\n');
var csv = from line in contents
          select line.Split(',').ToArray();
```

The `csv` variable can then be used as in the following example:

```
int headerRows = 5;
foreach (var row in csv.Skip(headerRows)
    .TakeWhile(r => r.Length > 1 && r.Last().Trim().Length > 0))
{
    String zerothColumnValue = row[0]; // leftmost column
    var firstColumnValue = row[1];
}
```

Comment: How do you access the rows and columns in the csv variable?

Comment: how do you handle escape comma?

Comment: Does not handle commas within columns. Better to use the robust library [CsvHelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper) as per joshb's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16193999/224976)

Comment: Which answer are you referring to? The one that is top-voted can change.

Answer (score 12):

If you need to skip (head-)lines and/or columns, you can use this to create a 2-dimensional array:

```
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path).Select(a => a.Split(';'));
    var csv = (from line in lines               
               select (from col in line
               select col).Skip(1).ToArray() // skip the first column
              ).Skip(2).ToArray(); // skip 2 headlines
```

This is quite useful if you need to shape the data before you process it further (assuming the first 2 lines consist of the headline, and the first column is a row title - which you don't need to have in the array because you just want to regard the data).

**N.B.** You can easily get the headlines and the 1st column by using the following code:

```
    var coltitle = (from line in lines 
                    select line.Skip(1).ToArray() // skip 1st column
                   ).Skip(1).Take(1).FirstOrDefault().ToArray(); // take the 2nd row
    var rowtitle = (from line in lines select line[0] // take 1st column
                   ).Skip(2).ToArray(); // skip 2 headlines
```

This code example assumes the following structure of your `*.csv` file:

[image: CSV Matrix]

**Note:** If you need to skip empty rows - which can by handy sometimes, you can do so by inserting

```
    where line.Any(a=>!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(a))
```

between the `from` and the `select` statement in the **LINQ** code examples above.

Answer (score 11):

You can use Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser dll in C# for better performance

get below code example from above article

```
static void Main()
{
    string csv_file_path=@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.csv";

    DataTable csvData = GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(csv_file_path);

    Console.WriteLine("Rows count:" + csvData.Rows.Count);

    Console.ReadLine();
}


private static DataTable GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(string csv_file_path)
{
    DataTable csvData = new DataTable();

    try
    {

    using(TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(csv_file_path))
        {
            csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
            csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
            string[] colFields = csvReader.ReadFields();
            foreach (string column in colFields)
            {
                DataColumn datecolumn = new DataColumn(column);
                datecolumn.AllowDBNull = true;
                csvData.Columns.Add(datecolumn);
            }

            while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
            {
                string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();
                //Making empty value as null
                for (int i = 0; i < fieldData.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (fieldData[i] == "")
                    {
                        fieldData[i] = null;
                    }
                }
                csvData.Rows.Add(fieldData);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    return csvData;
}
```

Comment: It's not as efficient because Split doesn't do everything that TextFieldParser does.  For example, skip comment lines, handle quoted fields, and remove beginning/trailing whitespace.  Not exactly a 1:1 comparison.

Answer (score 8):

I have spend few hours searching for a right library, but finally I wrote my own code :)
You can read file (or database) with whatever tools you want and then apply the following routine to each line:

```
private static string[] SmartSplit(string line, char separator = ',')
{
    var inQuotes = false;
    var token = "";
    var lines = new List<string>();
    for (var i = 0; i < line.Length; i++) {
        var ch = line[i];
        if (inQuotes) // process string in quotes, 
        {
            if (ch == '"') {
                if (i<line.Length-1 && line[i + 1] == '"') {
                    i++;
                    token += '"';
                }
                else inQuotes = false;
            } else token += ch;
        } else {
            if (ch == '"') inQuotes = true;
            else if (ch == separator) {
                lines.Add(token);
                token = "";
                } else token += ch;
            }
    }
    lines.Add(token);
    return lines.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Hi all, I created a static class for doing this.
+ column check
+ quota sign removal**

```
public static class CSV
{
    public static List<string[]> Import(string file, char csvDelimiter, bool ignoreHeadline, bool removeQuoteSign)
    {
        return ReadCSVFile(file, csvDelimiter, ignoreHeadline, removeQuoteSign);
    }

    private static List<string[]> ReadCSVFile(string filename, char csvDelimiter, bool ignoreHeadline, bool removeQuoteSign)
    {
        string[] result = new string[0];
        List<string[]> lst = new List<string[]>();

        string line;
        int currentLineNumner = 0;
        int columnCount = 0;

        // Read the file and display it line by line.  
        using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(filename))
        {
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                currentLineNumner++;
                string[] strAr = line.Split(csvDelimiter);
                // save column count of dirst line
                if (currentLineNumner == 1)
                {
                    columnCount = strAr.Count();
                }
                else
                {
                    //Check column count of every other lines
                    if (strAr.Count() != columnCount)
                    {
                        throw new Exception(string.Format("CSV Import Exception: Wrong column count in line {0}", currentLineNumner));
                    }
                }

                if (removeQuoteSign) strAr = RemoveQouteSign(strAr);

                if (ignoreHeadline)
                {
                    if(currentLineNumner !=1) lst.Add(strAr);
                }
                else
                {
                    lst.Add(strAr);
                }
            }

        }

        return lst;
    }
    private static string[] RemoveQouteSign(string[] ar)
    {
        for (int i = 0;i< ar.Count() ; i++)
        {
            if (ar[i].StartsWith("\"") || ar[i].StartsWith("'")) ar[i] = ar[i].Substring(1);
            if (ar[i].EndsWith("\"") || ar[i].EndsWith("'")) ar[i] = ar[i].Substring(0,ar[i].Length-1);

        }
        return ar;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var firstColumn = new List<string>();
var lastColumn = new List<string>();

// your code for reading CSV file

foreach(var line in file)
{
    var array = line.Split(';');
    firstColumn.Add(array[0]);
    lastColumn.Add(array[1]);
}

var firstArray = firstColumn.ToArray();
var lastArray = lastColumn.ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It might help to solve my problem. Actually I have to read data from file and then insert into database. At time of inserting I am getting primary key constraint error(as I already have data in database). So, I need to program such that with variable already exist then update the data.

Comment: I assume the first value if PK - you need to get a record by id from database and if it exists than issue an UPDATE statement, otherwise insert a new record.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a special case where one of data field has semicolon (";") as part of it's data in that case most of answers above will fail.

Solution in that case will be

```
string[] csvRows = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(FullyQaulifiedFileName);
string[] fields = null;
List<string> lstFields;
string field;
bool quoteStarted = false;
foreach (string csvRow in csvRows)
{
    lstFields = new List<string>();
    field = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < csvRow.Length; i++)
    {
        string tmp = csvRow.ElementAt(i).ToString();
        if(String.Compare(tmp,"\"")==0)
        {
            quoteStarted = !quoteStarted;
        }
        if (String.Compare(tmp, ";") == 0 && !quoteStarted)
        {
            lstFields.Add(field);
            field = "";
        }
        else if (String.Compare(tmp, "\"") != 0)
        {
            field += tmp;
        }
    }
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(field))
    {
        lstFields.Add(field);
        field = "";
    }
// This will hold values for each column for current row under processing
    fields = lstFields.ToArray(); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The open-source [Angara.Table](http://predictionmachines.github.io/Angara.Table/index.html) library allows to load CSV into typed columns, so you can get the arrays from the columns. Each column can be indexed both by name or index. See http://predictionmachines.github.io/Angara.Table/saveload.html.

The library follows RFC4180 for CSV; it enables type inference and multiline strings.

Example:

```
using System.Collections.Immutable;
using Angara.Data;
using Angara.Data.DelimitedFile;

...

ReadSettings settings = new ReadSettings(Delimiter.Semicolon, false, true, null, null);
Table table = Table.Load("data.csv", settings);
ImmutableArray<double> a = table["double-column-name"].Rows.AsReal;

for(int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", i, a[i]);
}
```

You can see a column type using the type Column, e.g.

```
Column c = table["double-column-name"];
Console.WriteLine("Column {0} is double: {1}", c.Name, c.Rows.IsRealColumn);
```

Since the library is focused on F#, you might need to add a reference to the FSharp.Core 4.4 assembly; click 'Add Reference' on the project and choose FSharp.Core 4.4 under "Assemblies" -> "Extensions".

Answer (score 2):

I have been using csvreader.com(paid component) for years, and I have never had a problem.  It is solid, small and fast, but you do have to pay for it.  You can set the delimiter to whatever you like.

```
using (CsvReader reader = new CsvReader(s) {
    reader.Settings.Delimiter = ';';
    reader.ReadHeaders();  // if headers on a line by themselves.  Makes reader.Headers[] available
    while (reader.ReadRecord())
        ... use reader.Values[col_i] ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am just student working on my master's thesis, but this is the way I solved it and it worked well for me. First you select your file from directory (only in csv format) and then you put the data into the lists.

```
List<float> t = new List<float>();
List<float> SensorI = new List<float>();
List<float> SensorII = new List<float>();
List<float> SensorIII = new List<float>();
using (OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog())
{
    try
    {
        dialog.Filter = "csv files (*.csv)|*.csv";
        dialog.Multiselect = false;
        dialog.InitialDirectory = ".";
        dialog.Title = "Select file (only in csv format)";
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var fs = File.ReadAllLines(dialog.FileName).Select(a => a.Split(';'));
            int counter = 0;
            foreach (var line in fs)
            {
                counter++;
                if (counter > 2)    // Skip first two headder lines
                {
                    this.t.Add(float.Parse(line[0]));
                    this.SensorI.Add(float.Parse(line[1]));
                    this.SensorII.Add(float.Parse(line[2]));
                    this.SensorIII.Add(float.Parse(line[3]));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(
            "Error while opening the file.\n" + exc.Message, 
            this.Text, 
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
            MessageBoxIcon.Error
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my **2 simple static methods** to convert text from csv file to `List<List<string>>` and vice versa. Each method use row convertor.

This code should take into account all the possibilities of the csv file. You can **define own csv separator** and this methods try to correct **escape double 'quote' char**, and deals with the situation when all text in quotes are one cell and **csv separator is inside quoted string** including **multiple lines in one cell** and can **ignore empty rows**.

*Last method is only for testing. So you can ignore it, or test your own, or others solution with this test method :). For testing I used this hard csv with 2 rows on 4 lines:*

```
0,a,""bc,d
"e, f",g,"this,is, o
ne ""lo
ng, cell""",h
```

**This is final code.** For simplicity, I removed all try catch blocks.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public static class Csv {
  public static string FromListToString(List<List<string>> csv, string separator = ",", char quotation = '"', bool returnFirstRow = true)
  {
    string content = "";
    for (int row = 0; row < csv.Count; row++) {
      content += (row > 0 ? Environment.NewLine : "") + RowFromListToString(csv[row], separator, quotation);
    }
    return content;
  }

  public static List<List<string>> FromStringToList(string content, string separator = ",", char quotation = '"', bool returnFirstRow = true, bool ignoreEmptyRows = true)
  {
    List<List<string>> csv = new List<List<string>>();
    string[] rows = content.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    if (rows.Length <= (returnFirstRow ? 0 : 1)) { return csv; }
    List<string> csvRow = null;
    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rows.Length; rowIndex++) {
      (List<string> row, bool rowClosed) = RowFromStringToList(rows[rowIndex], csvRow, separator, quotation);
      if (rowClosed) { if (!ignoreEmptyRows || row.Any(rowItem => rowItem.Length > 0)) { csv.Add(row); csvRow = null; } } // row ok, add to list
      else { csvRow = row; } // not fully created, continue
    }
    if (!returnFirstRow) { csv.RemoveAt(0); } // remove header
    return csv;
  }

  public static string RowFromListToString(List<string> csvData, string separator = ",", char quotation = '"')
  {
    csvData = csvData.Select(element =>
    {
      if (element.Contains(quotation)) {
        element = element.Replace(quotation.ToString(), quotation.ToString() + quotation.ToString());
      }
      if (element.Contains(separator) || element.Contains(Environment.NewLine)) {
        element = "\"" + element + "\"";
      }
      return element;
    }).ToList();
    return string.Join(separator, csvData);
  }

  public static (List<string>, bool) RowFromStringToList(string csvRow, List<string> continueWithRow = null, string separator = ",", char quotation = '"')
  {
    bool rowClosed = true;
    if (continueWithRow != null && continueWithRow.Count > 0) {
      // in previous result quotation are fixed so i need convert back to double quotation
      string previousCell = quotation.ToString() + continueWithRow.Last().Replace(quotation.ToString(), quotation.ToString() + quotation.ToString()) + Environment.NewLine;
      continueWithRow.RemoveAt(continueWithRow.Count - 1);
      csvRow = previousCell + csvRow;
    }

    char tempQuote = (char)162;
    while (csvRow.Contains(tempQuote)) { tempQuote = (char)(tempQuote + 1); }
    char tempSeparator = (char)(tempQuote + 1);
    while (csvRow.Contains(tempSeparator)) { tempSeparator = (char)(tempSeparator + 1); }

    csvRow = csvRow.Replace(quotation.ToString() + quotation.ToString(), tempQuote.ToString());
    if(csvRow.Split(new char[] { quotation }, StringSplitOptions.None).Length % 2 == 0) { rowClosed = !rowClosed; }
    string[] csvSplit = csvRow.Split(new string[] { separator }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    List<string> csvList = csvSplit
      .ToList()
      .Aggregate("",
          (string row, string item) => {
              if (row.Count((ch) => ch == quotation) % 2 == 0) { return row + (row.Length > 0 ? tempSeparator.ToString() : "") + item; }
              else { return row + separator + item; }
          },
          (string row) => row.Split(tempSeparator).Select((string item) => item.Trim(quotation).Replace(tempQuote, quotation))
      ).ToList();
    if (continueWithRow != null && continueWithRow.Count > 0) {
      return (continueWithRow.Concat(csvList).ToList(), rowClosed);
    }
    return (csvList, rowClosed);
  }

  public static bool Test()
  {
    string csvText = "0,a,\"\"bc,d" + Environment.NewLine + "\"e, f\",g,\"this,is, o" + Environment.NewLine + "ne \"\"lo" + Environment.NewLine + "ng, cell\"\"\",h";
    List<List<string>> csvList = new List<List<string>>() { new List<string>() { "0", "a", "\"bc", "d" }, new List<string>() { "e, f", "g", "this,is, o" + Environment.NewLine + "ne \"lo" + Environment.NewLine + "ng, cell\"", "h" } };

    List<List<string>> csvTextAsList = Csv.FromStringToList(csvText);
    bool ok = Enumerable.SequenceEqual(csvList[0], csvTextAsList[0]) && Enumerable.SequenceEqual(csvList[1], csvTextAsList[1]);
    string csvListAsText = Csv.FromListToString(csvList);
    return ok && csvListAsText == csvText;
  }
}
```

**Usage examples**:

```cs
// get List<List<string>> representation of csv
var csvFromText = Csv.FromStringToList(csvAsText);

// read csv file with custom separator and quote
// return no header and ignore empty rows
var csvFile = File.ReadAllText(csvFileFullPath);
var csvFromFile = Csv.FromStringToList(csvFile, ";", '"', false, false);

// get text representation of csvData from List<List<string>>
var csvAsText = Csv.FromListToString(csvData);
```

**Notes:**
This: `char tempQuote = (char)162;` is first rare character from ASCI table. The script searches for this, or the first next few ascii character that is NOT in the text and uses it as a temporary escape and quote characters.

Answer (score 1):

Still wrong.  You need to compensate for "" in quotes.
Here is my solution Microsoft style csv.

```
               /// <summary>
    /// Microsoft style csv file.  " is the quote character, "" is an escaped quote.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName"></param>
    /// <param name="sepChar"></param>
    /// <param name="quoteChar"></param>
    /// <param name="escChar"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static List<string[]> ReadCSVFileMSStyle(string fileName, char sepChar = ',', char quoteChar = '"')
    {
        List<string[]> ret = new List<string[]>();

        string[] csvRows = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

        foreach (string csvRow in csvRows)
        {
            bool inQuotes = false;
            List<string> fields = new List<string>();
            string field = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < csvRow.Length; i++)
            {
                if (inQuotes)
                {
                    // Is it a "" inside quoted area? (escaped litteral quote)
                    if(i < csvRow.Length - 1 && csvRow[i] == quoteChar && csvRow[i+1] == quoteChar)
                    {
                        i++;
                        field += quoteChar;
                    }
                    else if(csvRow[i] == quoteChar)
                    {
                        inQuotes = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        field += csvRow[i];
                    }
                }
                else // Not in quoted region
                {
                     if (csvRow[i] == quoteChar)
                    {
                        inQuotes = true;
                    }
                    if (csvRow[i] == sepChar)
                    {
                        fields.Add(field);
                        field = "";
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        field += csvRow[i];
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(field))
            {
                fields.Add(field);
                field = "";
            }
            ret.Add(fields.ToArray());
        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't handle the case when there are newlines inside column values ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have a library that is doing exactly you need.

Some time ago I had wrote simple and fast enough library for work with CSV files. You can find it by the following link: https://github.com/ukushu/DataExporter/blob/master/Csv.cs

It works with CSV like with 2 dimensions array. Exactly like you need.

As example, in case of you need all of values of 3rd row only you need is to write:

```
Csv csv = new Csv();

csv.FileOpen("c:\\file1.csv");

var allValuesOf3rdRow = csv.Rows[2];
```

or to read 2nd cell of 3rd row:

```
var value = csv.Rows[2][1];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Headers are required in csv for json conversion in the below code**

You can use below code as is without making any changes.

**This code will work with two row headers or with one row header.**

[image]

Below code reads the **uploaded IForm File** and converts to memory stream.

If you want to use file path instead of uploaded file you can replace

new StreamReader(ms, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, true)) with new StreamReader("../../examplefilepath");

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    administrativesViewModel.csvFile.CopyTo(ms);
    ms.Position = 0;
    using (StreamReader csvReader = new StreamReader(ms, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, true))
    {
        List<string> lines = new List<string>();
        while (!csvReader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = csvReader.ReadLine();
            var values = line.Split(';');
            if (values[0] != "" && values[0] != null)
            {
                lines.Add(values[0]);
            }
        }
        var csv = new List<string[]>();
        foreach (string item in lines)
        {
            csv.Add(item.Split(','));
        }
        var properties = lines[0].Split(',');
        int csvI = 1;
        var listObjResult = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
        if (lines.Count() > 1)
        {
            var ln = lines[0].Substring(0, lines[0].Count() - 1);
            var ln1 = lines[1].Substring(0, lines[1].Count() - 1);
            var lnSplit = ln.Split(',');
            var ln1Split = ln1.Split(',');
            if (lnSplit.Count() != ln1Split.Count())
            {
                properties = lines[1].Split(',');
                csvI = 2;
            }
        }
        for (int i = csvI; i < csv.Count(); i++)
        {
            var objResult = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            if (csvI > 0)
            {
                var splitProp = lines[0].Split(":");
                if (splitProp.Count() > 1)
                {
                    if (splitProp[0] != "" && splitProp[0] != null && splitProp[1] != "" && splitProp[1] != null)
                    {
                        objResult.Add(splitProp[0], splitProp[1]);
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < properties.Length; j++)
                if (!properties[j].Contains(":"))
                {
                    objResult.Add(properties[j], csv[i][j]);
                }
            listObjResult.Add(objResult);
        }
        var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listObjResult);
        var result2 = JArray.Parse(result);
        Console.WriteLine(result2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

[look at this](https://github.com/bluetonice/Csv)

using CsvFramework;

using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CvsParser
{

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }        
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public int Amount { get; set; }

    public List<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }

}

public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var customerLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"Customers.csv");
        var orderLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"Orders.csv");
        var orderItemLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"OrderItemLines.csv");

        CsvFactory.Register<Customer>(builder =>
        {
            builder.Add(a => a.Id).Type(typeof(int)).Index(0).IsKey(true);
            builder.Add(a => a.Name).Type(typeof(string)).Index(1);
            builder.AddNavigation(n => n.Orders).RelationKey<Order, int>(k => k.CustomerId);

        }, false, ',', customerLines);

        CsvFactory.Register<Order>(builder =>
        {
            builder.Add(a => a.Id).Type(typeof(int)).Index(0).IsKey(true);
            builder.Add(a => a.CustomerId).Type(typeof(int)).Index(1);
            builder.Add(a => a.Quantity).Type(typeof(int)).Index(2);
            builder.Add(a => a.Amount).Type(typeof(int)).Index(3);
            builder.AddNavigation(n => n.OrderItems).RelationKey<OrderItem, int>(k => k.OrderId);

        }, true, ',', orderLines);


        CsvFactory.Register<OrderItem>(builder =>
        {
            builder.Add(a => a.Id).Type(typeof(int)).Index(0).IsKey(true);
            builder.Add(a => a.OrderId).Type(typeof(int)).Index(1);
            builder.Add(a => a.ProductName).Type(typeof(string)).Index(2);


        }, false, ',', orderItemLines);



        var customers = CsvFactory.Parse<Customer>();


    }
}
```

}