# Write a CSV file and open it without saving

Tags: c#, csv

Is it possible to create a CSV file with C#, open the file but not saving it?

Comment: Did you tried it first?

Comment: What do you mean by *not saving it*?

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282999/c-net-reading-csv-file?rq=1

Comment: Your question is not precise enough. What do you want ? A CSV stream writer which does not write to disk ? use MemoryStream, and then copy the stream to disk when you want to "save".

Comment: I just want to open the CSV format in a Excel file, but the file should not be saved somwhere.

Answer (score 1):

CSV is a format. You can build this format in memory without persisting it to disk. Is that what you mean? How do you want to "open" the file? For example Excel only works with existing files, or you can use interop to fill the data in a new document.

Comment: I wanted to open it with Excel, but I just want to write the data in it so the user can look at it and if he want to save it he can save where ever he want to.

Comment: Then take a look at [How to: Use COM Interop to Create an Excel Spreadsheet (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186(v=vs.80).aspx).