# Reading contents of CSV file

Tags: c#, csv

I have loaded a CSV file

Here is a sample of the content available in the CSV file

```
Name,Address,Address1,LandMark,User_location,City,State,Phone1,Phone2,Email,Category
Sriram Electricals and Plumbing Contractors,No 12, Vinayakar Koil Street Easa,"Back Side Of Therasa School,",Pallavaram,Chennai,Tamil Nadu,(044) 66590405,,sriram@gmail.com,Electrican
```

I've tried to convert the file to a list

```
public ActionResult UserCsv(HttpPostedFileBase uploadfile)
{      
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(uploadfile.InputStream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {   
         var reader = new CsvReader(sr); 
         //CSVReader will now read the whole file into an enumerable
         IEnumerable<UserCSVModel> records = reader.GetRecords<UserCSVModel>();
    }
}
```

Unable to get a correct output.

Comment: What language are you using?. Please add appropriate tags.

Comment: c# olny i used with csvhelper dll

Comment: Use LinqToCSV NuGet package, its too easy to use...

Comment: let me know any sample links

Comment: @ liaqat ali i tried but same result only i got by using linqticsv

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050112/how-to-read-a-csv-file-into-a-net-datatable)

Answer (score 0):

try this article:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/415732/Reading-and-Writing-CSV-Files-in-Csharp

Or this Q on stack over flow:

[Reading CSV file and storing values into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282999/c-net-reading-csv-file)

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look a http://www.filehelpers.net/. It's a great library for working with CSV files and will give you an Enumerable that you can work with