# C# Read a particular value from CSV file

Tags: c#, csv

I am a learner in C#. I want to read a particular value from the CSV file. I have learned the getting the csv file into a datatable through browsing. Please see the following code (Thanks to surendra jha) and my CSV file format. Say, I want to get what is the 'Volume' for 'ID' = 90.

**CSV file**

```
ID:Volume:Name
100:5600:A
95:5000:B
90:4500:C
85:4000:D
```

**Code for getting all the values:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;              
namespace DVHConsolePrj
{
   class Program
     {
       static void Main(string[] args)
         {
             readCsvFileData();
          }
        static void readCsvFileData()
         {            
            string path = @"C:\IDVolumeName.txt";           
            StreamReader streamreader = new StreamReader(path);
            DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
            int rowcount = 0;
            string[] columnname = null;
            string[] streamdatavalue = null;
            while (!streamreader.EndOfStream)
            {
               string streamrowdata = streamreader.ReadLine().Trim();
                 if (streamrowdata.Length > 0) 
                    {
                       streamdatavalue = streamrowdata.Split(':'); 
                       if (rowcount == 0)
                       {
                          rowcount = 1;
                          columnname = streamdatavalue;
                          foreach (string csvheader in columnname)
                          {
                             DataColumn datacolumn = new DataColumn(csvheader.ToUpper(), typeof(string));
                             datacolumn.DefaultValue = string.Empty;
                             datatable.Columns.Add(datacolumn);
                           }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                          DataRow datarow = datatable.NewRow();
                          for (int i = 0; i < columnname.Length; i++)
                          {
                           datarow[columnname[i]] = streamdatavalue[i] == null ?             string.Empty : streamdatavalue[i].ToString();
                           }
                           datatable.Rows.Add(datarow);
                         }
                   }
          }
          streamreader.Close();
          streamreader.Dispose();                         
          foreach (DataRow dr in datatable.Rows)
          {
              string rowvalues = string.Empty;
              foreach (string csvcolumns in columnname)
              {
                  rowvalues += csvcolumns + "=" + dr[csvcolumns].ToString() + "    ";
               }
              Console.WriteLine(rowvalues);
            }
           Console.ReadLine();
           }              
        }
     }
```

Comment: Search in google how to read csv file with C#. Here an example ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282999/reading-csv-file-and-storing-values-into-an-array. Anyway I strongly advice you to use OleDbConnection !

Comment: you can use [DataTable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50(v=vs.110).aspx) method for filtering

Comment: I have never seen a [tag:csv] file with `:` for delimiters before. I thought `CSV` stands for comma separated values.

Comment: But, I have a small probs.... Using the following code, I can retrieve 95 to 85 but not 100? I am puzzled. Here is the code which replaces 'foreach (DataRow..' string myID;
            Console.Write("Enter ID:");
            myID = Console.ReadLine();

            var filtered = datatable.Select(String.Format("ID = {0}", myID));
            if (filtered.Length > 0)
            {
               var Volume1 = filtered[0]["VOLUME"];
               Console.WriteLine("Volume is :{0}",Volume1);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

Answer (score 2):

Instead of parsing the file manually in a DataTable, then doing some Linq, use Linq directly on it, using [this library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library).

It works pretty well and is very efficient with big files.

For instance.

1) Add nuget package in your project, and the following line to be able to use it:

```
using LINQtoCSV;
```

2) define the class that olds the data

```
public class IdVolumeNameRow
{
    [CsvColumn(FieldIndex = 1)]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [CsvColumn(FieldIndex = 2)]
    public decimal Volume { get; set; }

    [CsvColumn(FieldIndex = 3)]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

3) and search for the value

```
    var csvAttributes = new CsvFileDescription
    {
        SeparatorChar = ':',
        FirstLineHasColumnNames = true
    };

    var cc = new CsvContext();

    var volume = cc.Read<IdVolumeNameRow>(@"C:\IDVolumeName.txt", csvAttributes)
            .Where(i => i.ID == "90")
            .Select(i => i.Volume)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public DataTable CSVToDataTable(string filename, string separator)
{
    try
    {
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filename);

        OleDbConnection con = 
            new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\"" +
            file.DirectoryName + "\";
            Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(" + separator + ")';")

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(string.Format
                                  ("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", file.Name), con);

        con.Open();

        DataTable tbl = new DataTable();

        using (OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            tbl = new DataTable("MyTable");
            adp.Fill(tbl);        
        }

        return tbl;
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
         throw ex;
     }
     finally()
     {
        con.Close();
     }  
}
```

You can try this code, it is build on the fly, it is possible little errors to exist. Check OleDbConnection. When you return the DataTable you can search in the table using LINQ.

```
var results = from myRow in myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
where myRow.Field<int>("ID") == 90
select myRow;
```

Here you can take the row with ID=90 !

Comment: how does this answer his question?

Comment: Easy, I return the CSV file in the DataTable. After that I'm using LINQ to find the correct value.

Comment: His question is explicitly how to get the Volume for ID 90. Your answer does not cover it in the slightest.

Comment: @Serv now you can check it how. I wrote it explicit he can LINQ the dataTable for every value.

Comment: Now that's more like it.

Comment: OP already have datatable with data, so answer can be reduced to 5 last lines :-)

Answer (score 0):

For filtering DataTable you can use [DataTable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50(v=vs.110).aspx) method like this

```
var filtered = dataTable.Select("ID = '90'");
```

`filtered` above is array of datarow that suitable for the condition, so for get value from first filtered row you can use something like

```
if(filtered.Length>0){
    var Volume = filtered[0]["VOLUME"];
}
```

Comment: string myID;
            Console.Write("Enter ID:");
            myID = Console.ReadLine();

            var filtered = datatable.Select(String.Format("ID = {0}", myID));
            if (filtered.Length > 0)
            {
               var Volume1 = filtered[0]["VOLUME"];
               Console.WriteLine("Volume is :{0}",Volume1);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

Comment: Thanks.. But, I have a small probs.... Using the following code, I can retrieve 95 to 85 but not 100? I am puzzled.

Comment: @kmothpur, try change string format to `String.Format("ID = '{0}'", myID)`

Comment: I did actually used that String.Format only. I have uploaded the code in the comment.....

Comment: @kmothpur in _string.Format_ from your comment - used simple place holder: _{0}_, in my comment: _'{0}'_, i mean quotes around placeholder

Comment: Sorry. Noted now and it works now.....Excellent... :-)