# Reading in a CSV file

Tags: c#, .net, csv, console-application

I have written a small program to read data from a `csv` file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main( string[] args )
        {    
            var reader = new StreamReader( File.OpenRead( @"C:\Users\Desktop\Results.csv" ) );

            List<string> listA = new List<string>();
            List<string> listB = new List<string>();

            while ( !reader.EndOfStream )
            {
                var line   = reader.ReadLine();
                var values = line.Split( ',' );

                listA.Add( values[0] );
                listB.Add( values[1] );
            }

            // Print column one.
            Console.WriteLine( "Column 1:" );
            foreach ( var element in listA )
                Console.WriteLine( element );

            // Print column two.
            Console.WriteLine( "Column 2:" );
            foreach ( var element in listB )
                Console.WriteLine( element );

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error message on line `listB.Add( values[1] );`

```
Index was outside the bounds of the array.
```

When I comment out everything to do with `listB`, it works and shows me the 1st column...

Could someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Thank you,

Comment: what is the value of `values`? Is it being populated with anything? What is the string it should have been populated with?

Comment: Step through the code in the debugger and you will most likely quickly find the issue.

Comment: No pun intended, Why everyone try to write their own CSV parsers when there are very nice libraries available (e.g http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)?

Comment: Excellent snippet, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error probably occurs because a line was read that doesnt have a "," char or text behind it. Therefore values[1] does not exist and the error gets thrown. You can check for that case for example with

```
if(values.length < 2)
{
    //do what ever is needed in your case
}
```

or you make sure that the file that you are reading has at least 2 values seperated by a "," on every line. A line like

> text1,

would cause that error for example.

Answer (score 1):

That's because your this line `line.Split( ',' );` must be returning, a single item. Your returned array `values` has only one element.

You should check if any element is present before adding, something like this:-

```
if(values.Length > 1)
    listB.Add( values[1] );
```

Answer (score 0):

On the one of  the line in your **file/document** you don't have any spliting. I mean you don't have

```
value,value
```

You can make check if the `string` array contain two values and after that perform adding to the list or just fix your file.

Also you can try to see how to read csv file with `OleDbConnection`.

In this question I wrote how to read and store data in `DataTable`:
[C# Read a particular value from CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27378785/c-sharp-read-a-particular-value-from-csv-file/27379094#27379094)

Answer (score 0):

Enumerate through your csv data like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace CSV_ReadCsvColumn
{
    class Program
    {
        private static IEnumerable<string[]> LoadCsvData(string path, params char[] separator)
        {
            return from line in File.ReadLines(path)
                   let parts = (from p in line.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) select p)
                   select parts.ToArray();
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            IEnumerable<string[]> lines = LoadCsvData(@"file.csv", ';');

            if (lines != null)
            {
                // Print column one.
                foreach (var line in lines)
                    Console.WriteLine(line[0]);

                // Print column two.
                foreach (var line in lines)
                    Console.WriteLine(line[1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```