# How to write on multiple worksheets using EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I'm using the following code snippet to write some data into an excel file using EPPlus. My application does some big data processing and since excel has a limit of ~1 million rows, space runs out time to time. So what I am trying to achieve is this, once a `System.ArgumentException : row out of range` is detected or in other words.. no space is left in the worksheet.. the remainder of the data will be written in the 2nd worksheet in the same workbook. I have tried the following code but no success yet. Any help will be appreciated!

```
  try
                            {

                                for (int i = 0; i < data.Count(); i++)
                                {
                                    var cell1 = ws.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex];
                                    cell1.Value = data[i];
                                    colIndex++;
                                }
                                rowIndex++;
                            }
                            catch (System.ArgumentException)
                            {
                                for (int i = 0; i < data.Count(); i++)
                                {
                                    var cell2 = ws1.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex];
                                    cell2.Value = data[i];
                                    colIndex++;

                                }
                                rowIndex++;
                            }
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldnt use a catch to handle that kind of logic - it is more for a last resort. Better to engineer you code to deal with your situation since this is very predictable.

The excel 2007 format has a hard limit of 1,048,576 rows.  With that, you know exactly how many rows you should put before going to a new sheet.  From there it is simple for loops and math:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Big_Row_Count_Test()
{
    var existingFile = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\temp.xlsx");
    if (existingFile.Exists)
        existingFile.Delete();

    const int maxExcelRows = 1048576;

    using (var package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
    {
        //Assume a data row count
        var rowCount = 2000000;

        //Determine number of sheets
        var sheetCount = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)rowCount/ maxExcelRows);

        for (var i = 0; i < sheetCount; i++)
        {
            var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(String.Format("Sheet{0}", i));
            var sheetRowLimit = Math.Min((i + 1)*maxExcelRows, rowCount);

            //Remember +1 for 1-based excel index
            for (var j = i * maxExcelRows + 1; j <= sheetRowLimit; j++)
            {
                var cell1 = ws.Cells[j - (i*maxExcelRows), 1];
                cell1.Value = j;
            }
        }

        package.Save();
    }
}
```

Comment: How can i assume a value for rowcount in my case? It can be anything based on the data

Comment: Its a variable.  So get it from your data source and then plug it into the sheetCount formula.  What is your data source exactly?

Comment: little off topic: for inserting data from database you can use `LoadFromDataTable` function to quickly load data which is quicker than looping through rows and columns.

Comment: @Nimesh The thing with `LoadFromDataTable` is that it can get very slow with very large datasets due to the overhead it adds.  See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30709328/slow-loading-of-csv-files-using-epplus/30710690  In this case it is actually faster to use a for loop.

Comment: @Ernie My initial code was using loops as I was not aware about `LoadfromDataTable` but I noticed quite improvement in my case, maybe the datasets were not that huge. Will have to experiment and see. Thanks.