# Unable to read from a CSV using List<string>

Tags: c#, csv

I have seen the following code used in other posts and it seems to be accepted as an answer but when I use it, it doesn't work correctly. Its purpose is to pull the last three lines of a text file and output them to the user.

I do not receive any build errors, but the console doesn't output the contents of the given .csv.

```
List<string> test = File.ReadAllLines("test.csv").Reverse().Take(3).Reverse().ToList();

Console.WriteLine(test);
```

**EDIT:**

This posted without the full post.

The contents of the csv are numbers 0-10 and I need to pull the last three numbers of the file upon request.

For testing purposes, the csv is currently laid out:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I want to pull the numbers in the order of 3, 4, 5.

Comment: It would appreciable if you could let us know how your csv looks like and what is the expected output.

Comment: What is in the file? What is being printed to console? Create a [mcve].

Comment: "it doesn't work correctly" What does this mean? What do get instead of the expected?

Comment: Follow Ryan Searle answer. With a foreach to write the list contents it works just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example will print something like "System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.String]" This is because the `Console.WriteLine()` is expecting a string (which it may be receive using the object's ToString() method) yet you pass it a `List<>` object whose ToString() method returns "System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.String]".

Instead you need to retrieve each string from the list with a `foreach` loop and then print each string as you retrieve it.

For Example:

```
var lst = new List<string>();

lst.Add("test1");
lst.Add("test2");
lst.Add("test3");           

foreach (var item in lst)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item); // item, not list
}
Console.Read();
```

Comment: This still outputs _"System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.String]"_ though, any ideas?

Comment: **Fixed** WriteLine is item, not lst. Code now working, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you're `WriteLine`ing is a value of `List<string>.ToString()`, which is not what you want. Try `foreach`ing over the `test` list and `WriteLine` each line separately.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(var item in test )
{
Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this:

```
using System.IO;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\test.csv"));
    List<string> listA = new List<string>();
    List<string> listB = new List<string>();
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        var values = line.Split(';');

        listA.Add(values[0]);
        listB.Add(values[1]);
    }

    foreach(var item in listA )
    {
       Console.WriteLine(item);
    }

    foreach(var item in listB )
    {
       Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

[Link to the Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282999/reading-csv-file-and-storing-values-into-an-array)

Comment: Don't copy answers. Don't parse CSV using `string.Split()`.

Comment: Instead of copying the code of that related answer you may simply have flagged the question as a duplicate.

Comment: ok thanks for the information. I dont copy code anymore. But I imporved the answere. And I only copy the code above without telling were it is from.

Comment: See the OPs update. There is no need to split the lines within the file as only one item is contained per line. Thus your answer is obsolete.