# Searching Two columns from csv file and then displaying the result in console(Ticket Reservation System)?

Tags: c#, csv, ticket-system

I want to search two columns from CSV file like the data of Flying From and Flying To and then display the result in console. I have tried searching and everything is really hard for me to understand. Appreciate your support.

Comment: Please read [Ask] and also take the [Tour]

Answer (score 0):

You could use this code from the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282999/reading-csv-file-and-storing-values-into-an-array)

```
using System.IO;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\test.csv"));
    List<string> listFlyingFrom = new List<string>();
    List<string> listFlyingTo = new List<string>();
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        var values = line.Split(';');

        listFlyingFrom.Add(values[0]);
        listFlyingTo.Add(values[1]);
    }
}
```

or you create a new object:

```
public class Flying {
    public string FlyingFrom { get; private set; }
    public string FlyingTo { get; private set; }

    public Flying(string from, string to) {
        FlyingFrom = from;
        FlyingTo = to;
    }
}

using System.IO;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead("test.csv"));
        List<Flying> flying = new List<Flying>();
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var values = line.Split(';');

            flying.Add(new Flying(values[0], values[1]));
        }

        string userSelection = "fromA";
        Flying result = flying.Find(f => f.FlyingFrom.Equals(userSelection));
        Console.WriteLine(result.FlyingFrom + ": " + result.FlyingTo);
}
```

Comment: I tried this method but had problem like it was not searching two columns but searching only one and when I wanted to display it on the console it only showed same column twice.

Comment: you also used `values[1]` ?

Comment: Yes bro. sorry i did not mention it earlier that i want the data to be displayed when user enters the location then the program searches for it and then displays the result.

Comment: I dont know what is the problem.

Comment: Can you display the error message? What is in the `flying` list?