# C# - Splitting by columns on a CSV file

Tags: c#, csv

I want to import some data from a csv file, but I've encountered a small problem I can't really figure out.

The person who gave me this file, added comma seperated values in cells, so when I split them they will be added to the list. Instead, I would like to get all values per column as a string, I just can't really figure out how.

For example, the column I'm talking about, is about the days a restaurant is open. This can be `Mo, Tu, We, Su`, but it can also be `Mo, Tu`.

Is there a way I can just loop over de values per column, instead of by the comma seperated values?

I'm currently using it like this, but this just adds each day to the total list of values:

```
using (var fs = File.OpenRead(csvUrl))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        if (i > 0)
        {
            var values = line.Split(',');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading CSV file and storing values into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282999/reading-csv-file-and-storing-values-into-an-array)

Comment: split by comma whcih will yield you a array or list on which you can loop over

Comment: @RajshekarReddy Like I said, that adds each seperate day as a single value in the array. I want to group the values together per column.

Comment: So, is there some sort of quoted-field for the comma-containing cells?

Comment: @grek40 nope, it's literally just `mo, tu, we`

Comment: can you provide a sample of the input? are the columns containing commas wrapped in quotes?

Comment: So, how would you ever distinguish between a change of cells and a cell-internal list of values?

Comment: So you mean to say the file is `comma-separated-values` and also your values have a `comma` in it? is that what you say

Comment: @RandomStranger also note that `csv` can have any character used as a separator.. meaning you can have `,` or `tabs` or any other character.. But the issue is if at all it is comma separated and also you have values with comma in it.. you better make sure that is handled properly..

Comment: @RajshekarReddy I didn't know that, sorry..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `TextFieldParser` to parse CSV files:

```
TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(new StringReader(lineContent));
parser.SetDelimiters(",");
string[] rawFields = parser.ReadFields();
```

`lineContent` is a `string` with the content of the current line in your file.

`TextFieldParser` is available in the namespace:

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO
```

Don't mind abaout the Visual Basic part it works fine in C#

**EDIT**

In your code you could implement it like this:

```
using (var fs = File.OpenRead(csvUrl))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        if (i > 0)
        {
            TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(new StringReader(lineContent));
            parser.SetDelimiters(",");
            string[] rawFields = parser.ReadFields();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you! I'll accept it whenever SO lets me

Answer (score 2):

Best solution so far to deal with CSV values is using the .NET built in libraries:
Its explained here in my StackOverflow answer here:
[Reading CSV file and storing values into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282999/reading-csv-file-and-storing-values-into-an-array/33796861#33796861)

For easy reference, I am including the code here as well.

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;

var path = @"C:\Person.csv"; // Habeeb, "Dubai Media City, Dubai"
using (TextFieldParser csvParser = new TextFieldParser(path))
{
 csvParser.CommentTokens = new string[] { "#" };
 csvParser.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
 csvParser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

 // Skip the row with the column names
 csvParser.ReadLine();

 while (!csvParser.EndOfData)
 {
  // Read current line fields, pointer moves to the next line.
  string[] fields = csvParser.ReadFields();
  string Name = fields[0];
  string Address = fields[1];
 }
}
```

More details about the parser is given here: http://codeskaters.blogspot.ae/2015/11/c-easiest-csv-parser-built-in-net.html