# Multidimensional Array for CSV-File in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, file, multidimensional-array, streamreader

Good Morning!
So I want to create a Multidimensional Array for a CSV-File in C#. I programmed this Code, but it doesn't work. Can somebody help me?

```
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\_repos\2021-3xhit-p1-team-02\Programm\CodeZuweisen.txt");

      
        string[,] info = new string[10,6];
        int line = 0;

        string content = sr.ReadToEnd();
        string[] s = content.Split(',');

        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {

            if (i % 6 == 0 && i!=0)
            {
                ++line;
            }
            else
            {
                info[line, i] = s[i];
            }
        }


        lblAusgabe.Text = info[1,2];
```

If I want to run this program, there is no output?
I already programmed it in java, and it also works, but I don't like C# :D.

Any kind of help would be awesome!
Have a nice day!

Comment: can you please show your data of excel...

Comment: it's a text file

Comment: Please post a [mcve] including your input and expected output, so we can replicate the problem.

Comment: Btw: you are not resetting `i`. There cannot be a non-null string in [1,2]. I wonder why you are _not_ getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException ... maybe I am missing something, here.

Comment: I think `info[line, i] = s[i];` should be `info[line, i%6] = s[i];` for starters.

Comment: _"I already programmed it in java, and it also works"_ - I have my doubts. The Java code for this should be _pretty_ close to what this code is. So if you have the same (="equivalent") in Java, it _cannot_ "work".

Comment: Without input/output and information about the error/issue you encounter. The mother dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282999/reading-csv-file-and-storing-values-into-an-array will be the way to go

Comment: @MD.RAKIBHASAN Thanks for the fast answer! This is my random created csv file. does,riding,addition,shop,wheat,got
various,purple,your,universe,roar,must
attention,throughout,tank,excellent,success,sunlight
therefore,sat,seldom,typical,born,sheet
done,prevent,announced,wooden,chest,higher
airplane,running,below,knew,gift,broke
magic,pretty,nearly,pitch,through,aware

Comment: @Fildor Thanks for the fast answer! This is my CSV filedoes,riding,addition,shop,wheat,got
various,purple,your,universe,roar,must
attention,throughout,tank,excellent,success,sunlight
therefore,sat,seldom,typical,born,sheet
done,prevent,announced,wooden,chest,higher
airplane,running,below,knew,gift,broke
magic,pretty,nearly,pitch,through,aware

Comment: @Fildor I want to put them in a multidimensional array called string info[column,row]. For example the word "throughout" in my CSV-File is saved in the string[1,1]

Comment: @Fildor java: while(scanner.hasNext()){
                    String line = scanner.nextLine();
                    String[] s = line.split(" ");
                    for (int m = 0; m < s.length ; m++) {
                        d[i][m] = s[m];
                        System.out.println(s[m]);
                    }
                    i++;
                }

Comment: ^^ See? Here you split by lines first, then by splitter. Quite a different enough approach for it to work but the C# version not.

Comment: Addn information in the question using the [edit] button. Format does not survive in comment.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `string.Split(',')` isn't a CSV parsing tool. You should use a dedicated CSV parser and a strongly typed output, eg. [CSV Helper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/).

Secondly, `ReadToEnd` will give you one long string. The solve is to split by *new line* first. However, it's probably easier to use a *jagged array* here (which will produce a `string[][]`). Jagged arrays are a little easier to work with as you can use standard Linq methods that take an `IEnumerable` and you don't need to dig out the dimensions all the time.

**Example**

```
var myArray = File.ReadAllLines("FileName")
                  .Select(x => x.Split(','))
                  .ToArray();

// print the results to screen
foreach (var line in myArray)
   Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", line));
```